# Set hyperlinks and anchors on libreoffice

Tags: hyperlink, libreoffice-writer

In word you could select a sentence and set an anchor on it, so a hyperlink could reference this part of the document. Is this feature possible under Libreoffice Writer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can set a "bookmark" and use it as target for a hyperlink. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Select the **"anchor" sentence or word**;
2. **Set a bookmark on it**: Menu `Insert` -> `Bookmark...`; in the dialogue, set a distinct name for the new bookmark:

   [image: Insert Bookmark]
3. Select the **sentence or word that should point to the bookmark previously created**;
4. **Set a hyperlink on the selection**: Menu `Insert` -> `Hyperlink`; the Hyperlink Dialogue will appear:

   [image: Insert Hyperlink]
5. In the column of hyperlink targets at the left, **make sure that `Document` is selected**; also, make sure that the `Path` text field is empty so the hyperlink points to the current document;
6. **Set the hyperlink target**: either enter the Bookmark name preceded by a `#`, or hit the `Target in document` button to select the bookmark from a tree view:

   [image: Set target]

   [image: Target from document]

   [image: Insert hyperlink]